# UITextView hide keyboard in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, keyboard-events

I want to hide keyboard when a user presses return in `UITextView` object in iphone. However, mysteriously this is not working for `UITextView` but working for `UITextField`. I am unable to figure out why...

This is what I did:

1) I created a view based application in XCode4.

2) in .xib created `UITextView`, `UITextField` and `UIButton` objects

***3) Marked both `UITextField` and `UITextView` delegates to File's Owner in Outlets***

4) Added `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to @interface UIViewController in .h

5) Added `textFieldShouldReturn` function in .m

Here are the codes:

**.h file**

```
@interface keyboardDisappearViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{

    UITextView *textBoxLarge;
    UITextField *textBoxLittle;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textBoxLarge;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textBoxLittle;

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField 
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn Fired :)");
    [textBoxLarge resignFirstResponder];
    [textBoxLittle resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Amazingly, the keyboard is disappearing in case of textBoxLittle (UITextField) but not in case of textBoxLarge(UITextView)

As a further check I, made the button to call function doSomething

```
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender {
    [textBoxLarge resignFirstResponder];
    [textBoxLittle resignFirstResponder];
}
```

When I am pressing the button, keyboard is disappearing in both textboxes.

Its driving me nuts why textFieldShouldReturn is working for small textbox, but NOT for large textbox.

Please Help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write code in `UITextViewDelegate` and assign it to your class.

Comment: -- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

    [textView resignFirstResponder];

     }
    return YES;

}

Comment: I got it I have written `@interface keyboardDisappearViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>` How to write both `<UITextFieldDelegate> and <UITextViewDelegate>`

Comment: yeah in .m file. In .h file confrom to uitextviewdelegate as u did for textfeilddelegate

Comment: writing like this 
`@interface keyboardDisappearViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> <UITextViewDelegate>`
is giving errors (which is obvious). How to conform to both in one statement?

Comment: simple : <UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>

Comment: However its still not working... :( The keyboard hides for textfield but not for textView... :( :(

Comment: No. All my code is same as above. I just changed <UITextFieldDelegate> to `@interface keyboardDisappearViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>` textBoxLittle is working good already. I figured that adding/removing <UITextFieldDelegate> hasnt made any difference to textBoxLittle... Its only the uitextview thats creating problems

Answer (score 20):

Three things:

Make your view implement UITextViewDelegate.

```
@interface keyboardDisappearViewController : UIViewController
    <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>
```

Add the following method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView
        shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
        replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Set the file's owner as delegate for the UITextView in the interface builder.

(BTW: Solution copied from the comments to the previous answer, as it took me a while to extract. I though others could benefit from my experience.)

Answer (score 5):

Simple trick
Set `delegate` for your text view and then

```
doSomething 
{

}
```

action connect to ext view for `control event didEndOnExit and tuchupinside`

---

// To dismiss key board when user clicks enter/return

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text 
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) 
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

Inherit UITextViewDelegate protocol in your Viewcontroller add the text

```
@interface YourViewController () <UITextViewDelegate>
```

In viewDidLoad set yourself as a delegate:

```
yourUITextView.delegate = self;
```

Implement the delegate method below:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{ 
   return NO; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Key Points**

- Someone needs to be listening for the Return Key press

  - *UITextFieldDelegate*
  - *textFieldShouldReturn(textField : UITextField)*
- Someone needs to manually dismiss the keyboard

  - *resignFirstResponder()*

**#1:** Create a UITextFieldDelegate and assign it as the delegate to your UITextField -

```
exampleTextField.delegate = yourUITextFieldDelegate;
```

**#2:** Have 'yourUITextFieldDelegate' contain the following -

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField : UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.titleField.resignFirstResponder();   //Here's the key!!!!!

    return true;                              //true just says 'default behavior'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you came here looking for the Swift solution, like I did, here you are :)

```
extension keyboardDisappearViewController : UITextViewDelegate {
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(text == "\n") {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have coded in the .h file:

```
@interface keyboardDisappearViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UITextView *textBoxLarge;
    UITextField *textBoxLittle;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textBoxLarge;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textBoxLittle;

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
@end
```

It should be:

```
@interface keyboardDisappearViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UITextView *textBoxLarge;
    UITextField *textBoxLittle;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textBoxLarge;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textBoxLittle;

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: You changed the `IBOutlet`, but didn't change the ivar? He probably shouldn't have the ivar in the first place, but rather just let the compiler synthesize it, but certainly having the ivar not match the property can't be good. And, anyway, telling him not to use a `UITextView` just sidesteps the question, given that was the problem he was trying to solve.