# How to call textViewShouldEndEditing method for UITextview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my UITextView, I have done editing, I want my textViewShouldEndEditing to be called to remove keyboard focus. I have tried with return key, but it is adding new line. What can I do to remove keyboard for UITextView. I have done with textfield it has SentNotification. What to do here?

Comment: You can use this: [self.myTextView resignFirstResponder];

Comment: [self.txtMobileNumber resignFirstResponder];

Comment: I can do this once my method is called,

Comment: In that case you can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680693/uitextview-hide-keyboard-in-iphone

Comment: it is better to add toolbar with done button up on keyboard

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6275-add-toolbar-on-top-of-keyboard.html

Comment: @Prince I will check about this thanks.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>In order to enable the return key to dismiss the keyboard, implement</strike>

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return NO; // to not insert the return character
}
```

Implement a button in your navigation bar that dismisses the keyboard with

```
[_textView resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Sorry - overlooked that.

Comment: I think You didn't understand my question. I want to add multiple line so I can't override the return key to resign first responder. In this case I want to remove keyboard. Other than return key click I want to remove keyboard focus. Any Idea?

Comment: Don't understand your last sentence...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the keyboard after pressing the return key, implement the following *UITextViewDelegate* method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    // Did user press return key?
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        // tell the textView to resign being first responder, which will also hide the keyboard
        [textView resignFirstResponder];

        // Don't allow textView to insert a LF into its text property
        return NO;
    }

    // allow all other edits
    return YES;
}
```

If you want to have multiple lines instead, you can't use the return key, so you have to create a button for this. Given your ViewController is pushed on the Navigation stack of an UINavigationController, add the following code to your init method:

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(done)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
[doneButton release];
```

The done method simply tells the UITextView to resign being first responder:

```
- (void)done;
{
    [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This obviously requires that you have access to your UITextView through a property or an IBOutlet.

In case you don't use a UINavigationController, add a simple UIButton to your View (for example via Interface Builder in your views XIB file) and call the *done* method via target action:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(done) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I want to have multiple lines, so how can I achieve that here?

Comment: I've extended my answer accordingly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set delegate for textview `UITextViewDelegate` in .h file and than write the following method to return keyboard.

```
-(void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
  [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```