# How to disable keyboard in UITextView or how make the return key work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uitextview

I am using `UITextView` without xib (programmatically). I have a text scrolling horizontally. I am not able to disable the keyboard, I've used:

```
textView.editable = NO;
```

Else I would like to use the return key which is also not working, I've used:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

NSLog(@"%@",textView.text);
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

Or can I have IBAction Option which I could programmatically...

Answer (score 0):

well i can tell something which works when someone touches anywhere after entering the data.
use this method

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event];
    [[self textView]resignFirstResponder];
}
```

here is a link which can which can help you to do the same using Delegation.

[UITextView hide keyboard in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680693/uitextview-hide-keyboard-in-iphone)

Comment: @Vinay Chopra This isnt working becoz i am not using Xib. if i use add Selector thing, it says UITextView/Field cannot use it.



[Text_view addTarget:self action:@selector(ReturnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventDidEndOnExit];

Comment: i think there is something wrong happening , as you have set the property textView.editable = NO; so Keyboard would not be appearing cos of that , there might be some testified or something else that is calling the keyboard and not resigning it . else i have tested its working smooth with me . Dude provide some more detail of your page so that i can help you out.

Comment: ok, do one thing add ALL your textfield and textViews to the above method (touchesBegan)   [[self myTexyField]resignFirstResponder]; then try it again and do let me know ?

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss the keyboard when done button is pressed use this

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
  if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Tried This isnt working.. my textview is made programaticaly.

Comment: Have you set the UITextView delegate to self. And keep the break point in this method to check this method is calling???